# ngRepeat animation on orderBy - not all elements are animated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have some problems with the usage of animations on ngRepeat. Indeed, when used along with the orderBy filter, not all the elements are animated.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VTZ5yqGGPizrwlGCMzNO?p=preview

On this example, you can see that when a sort criteria is selected, some items are animated but some other are not even if their position change.

How should I do to animate all the elements (or at least all elements which position changes)?

Thanks by advance. Valentin